# Producing a series based on the input: START, STEP, and END

Tags: java

So I was tasked to produced a series of numbers based on what I input on START, STEP, and END.
For example: If I input 5 on the START, 2 on the STEP, and 13 on the end, then the output would be:

5, 7, 9, 11, 13

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SeriesOfNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] numbers = {1 ,2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
        int start = 0;
        int step = 0;
        int end = 0;
        boolean foundNum = false;
        
        
        System.out.print("START: ");
        start = scan.nextInt();
        for(start = 0; start <= numbers.length; start++) {
            if(start == numbers.length) {
                foundNum = true;
                break;
            }
        }
                
        System.out.print("STEP: ");
        step = scan.nextInt();
        for(step = 0; step <= numbers.length; step++) {
            if(start == numbers.length) {
                foundNum = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("END:");
        end = scan.nextInt();
        for(end = 0; end <= numbers.length; end++) {
            if(end == numbers.length) {
                foundNum = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(foundNum) {
            System.out.print("The output will be: ");
        }
        }
    }
```

Expected output:

```
START: 5

STEP: 3

END: 20

The output will be: 5 8 11 14 17 20
```

Since I'm new to JAVA and it's my first programming language, I have no idea what I am doing. A little assistance might help. Thank you!

Comment: Take a close look at all of your `for` loops. You START by initializing a variable with some value, you END when you reach a certain value and in each iteration you increment the variable by some STEP (always 1 in your case). I wonder if that can somehow be generalized. More bluntly: you don't need arrays for this at all, you need exactly a single simple for loop that doesn't use fixed, constant values but the 3 values entered by the user instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple program according to your description.

Notes:

1. The variable int[] numbers and boolean foundNum was never used
2. You only needed a single for loop for your said program.
3. Closing your object Scanner is a good practice.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SeriesOfNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("START: ");
        int start = scan.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("STEP: ");
        int step = scan.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("END: ");
        int end = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("The output will be: ");
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }

        scan.close();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple loops here. Your `start`, `step` and `end` variables are sufficient to produce your output in one loop.

```
for (int i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
  System.out.print(i + " "); // just an example - you could add the number to a list instead
}
```